# Replace last row of column with last row of another column in R

Tags: r

I need to replace the last row of each group with the last row from another column. Previously I've been able to do this by making all the data but the last row zero, and then using `ifelse` to `mutate` a column taking only values above 0. But then the last row was always the lowest value so I could use `case_when` to select only the lowest value. Now the data is random and the size has no relation to its placement.

In this case I want the last value from PCAR1 to replace the last value in PCAR.

I've been trying to use `slice` or `tail` but I'm just getting errors returned.  So far I have something that looks like:

```
df <- df%>%
  group_by(time_bin)%>%
  mutate(PCAR1 = ifelse(slice(1:(n()-1)), PCAR1, 0))%>%
  mutate(PCAR = ifelse(PCAR1 >0, PCAR1, PCAR))


#Data# 

df <- structure(list(time_bin = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200), PCAR1 = c(325.947943826017, 
339.835783930254, 310.492430685748, 332.43346350175, 199.54398828513, 
142.821605613045, 191.572198416637, 170.67567450243, 131.535087546719, 
329.624262985389, 229.99470258103, 217.344970472844, 157.85520203161, 
153.107703614107, 131.659911154268, 82.4153938744129, 162.845234183621, 
106.871069919164, 61.5051800997765, 126.922394965646, 87.0148189713542, 
95.0831508155524, 71.7975354573988, 32.3815944849868, 24.2498801736037, 
21.6391689024657, 14.8451420537953, 14.7021072370529, 19.0482898453303
), PCAR = c(377.981689418665, 325.947943826017, 339.835783930254, 
310.492430685748, 332.43346350175, 199.54398828513, 142.821605613045, 
191.572198416637, 170.67567450243, 131.535087546719, 329.624262985389, 
229.99470258103, 217.344970472844, 157.85520203161, 153.107703614107, 
131.659911154268, 82.4153938744129, 162.845234183621, 106.871069919164, 
61.5051800997765, 126.922394965646, 87.0148189713542, 95.0831508155524, 
71.7975354573988, 32.3815944849868, 24.2498801736037, 21.6391689024657, 
14.8451420537953, 14.7021072370529)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


Thanks!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` for each `time_bin` value.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(time_bin) %>% mutate(PCAR1 = replace(PCAR1, n(), last(PCAR)))
```

This will `replace` last `PCAR1` value with last value of `PCAR`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to construct a new vector:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(time_bin) %>%
  mutate(PCAR1 = c(PCAR1[-n()], PCAR[n()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, .I[.N], time_bin]$V1
df[i1, PCAR1 := PCAR]
```

---

Or using `duplicated` without having to use `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(PCAR1 =  case_when(!duplicated(time_bin, fromLast = TRUE) 
       ~ PCAR, TRUE ~ PCAR1))
```